# Propel PHP ORM with Oracle DB - Reverse engineer script

Tags: php, oracle, propel

I am having issues with integrating Oracle DB with Propel ORM 1.X. Below are the sample build properties that I have included

```
propel.project = TestProject
propel.php.dir = ${propel.output.dir}/models

propel.phpconf.dir = ${propel.output.dir}/config
propel.output.dir = ${propel.project.dir}/

propel.database = oracle
propel.database.url = oci:dbname=//<HostName>:<PortNo>/<SchemaName>

propel.database.buildUrl = {propel.database.url}

propel.database.user = <UserName>
propel.database.password = <Password>
propel.database.schema = <SchemaName>
```

However when I try to run the .reverse script, I am faced with this error:

> [propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/TestProj/vendor/propel/generator/build-propel.xml:296:1: invalid data source name

Could anyone please throw some light on this?

Comment: Did you check your `ropel.database.url` very carefully?

Comment: Yes, I did.. I also gathered it for oracle db from Propel documentation itself

Answer (score 0):

For running reverse engineer , Go to cmd ctr+r    and that go to propel generator bin file location. in my cases 
`C:\wamp\www\propel\generator\bin>propel-gen C:\wamp\www\Myproject reverse`   that all